# Word for adding material to a rough surface until a smooth surface is formed?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes rough surfaces are turned to smooth surfaces by adding material. For example, adding lacquer to wood. Any word for this process or its result?

Comment: I suspect there is no such term, partly because *successfully* adding lacquer to wood largely depends on the wood being smooth in the first place.

Can you describe your process with other media than wood or lacquer, please? Metal, for instance? Plaster? China?

Comment: Of course, if your process would *not* be comparable to but rather, necessary to facilitate adding lacquer to wood, you might mean *filling*, for which we buy specially made *filler*.

Answer (score 2):

The verb is "to finish":

> [finish, verb](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20%22to%20finish%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)
>
> complete the manufacture or decoration of (a material, object, or
>   place) by giving it an attractive surface appearance. "the interior
>   was finished with V-jointed American oak" synonyms:   varnish, lacquer,
>   veneer, coat, stain, wax, shellac, enamel, glaze "some items were
>   finished in a black lacquer"

finish is also a noun, referring to the end result of the process of finishing.

Answer (score -1):

The only word I can think of for the result is "smoothed".

Comment: Sorry, Llcoolerj, and *smoothing* necessarily means not *adding* but *removing*.